# monaco-editor: how do I parse out the text in the editor into property, operator and value etc

Tags: monaco-editor

I know how to get the text entered into the monaco-editor

```
    var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
                        value: ['aso.EnvironmentName = "DEV"'
                        ].join('\n'),
                        language: 'typescript'
 editor.getValue();
```

That gets me the following

```
aso.EnvironmentName = "DEV"
```

while what I want is something akin to this

```
{
object:'aso',
property:'EnvironmentName',
operator:'=',
value:'DEV'
}
```

This selector gets something the following which I could further parse with a "".split(' ')

```
$.each($('span[class^="mtk"]'),function(idx,s){
    console.info(idx,$(s).html());
});
```

gets me the following. I find it hard to believe that the monaco object can not return what I want as it provides a popup that identifies the EnvironmentName property as a property with type of string

```
0 "aso.EnvironmentName&nbsp;=&nbsp;"
1 ""DEV""
```

Is this something I can do from the editor's API? or do I need to send the text back to my service where I can use proper reflection tools?

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question....

The solution is to use [monaco.editor.tokenize()](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.editor.html#tokenize) and it returns an array of the index position of each token and its type

and then

```
let m = editor.getModel();
m.getWordAtPosition(m.getPositionAt(34))
```

to get the actual token

Comment: I am looking for something similar but for formula expressions, do you have an example implementation or a code base where I can take a look at ?

Comment: @Veryon890 unfortunately I don't anymore. I have left that job. Hopefully the documentation had gotten better.. I see it's still less than version 1 after 4 years. good luck